# Will using a computer with either Intel I-5 or I-7 stop audio from freezing while manipulating data files?

Tags: windows-10, audio

I have an older HP Pavilion G7 series laptop where the processor is Core I-3. I do a lot of data manipulation with files and file folders. Anytime I am working with "file explorer" and listening to audio through the computer the music will pause for a brief time (2-4 seconds) during the file manipulation period. Via moving files or creating new file folders. It doesn't seem to matter whether I am listening to audio through Youtube or listening through a media player etc wmp or vlc, or mpc-hc. Would more memory help too?

Comment: Your problem with the audio has nothing to do with the CPU you have in your laptop.  Even if you wanted to upgrade the CPU in your laptop, you can't, because it isn't user replaceable.  Even if you did find a way to remove it and replace the CPU, it wouldn't solve your audio problems, your relative weak CPU has nothing to do with your audio problems.

Comment: Maybe it's your driver issue. Updating audio driver could solve the problem.

Comment: this sounds like a DPC issue: http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=140263

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like the Sound is on a shared IRQ with another higher priority device. When you are doing other things such as a file manipulation, the sound can be "interrupted" by the higher priority IRQ devices and probably what you are hearing.

I wouldn't consider this a "problem" of the CPU or the RAM.

You could try uninstall the sound in the Device Manager (but not the drivers) then restart the PC and when Windows starts it will detect and reinstall the sound. Sometimes Windows will reinstall this on a different shared IRQ and fix (or change) the original symptom.  This may help if windows 7 or earlier.

Also I would note down what IRQ the sound card is using and what other devices are sharing that IRQ.

Comment: Thanks for your input I will check this out. It would not be cost effective to change out even I could the cpu. I can and have learned to live with this. Thanks for the answers